# using texlive 2013 and 2014 in parallel

Tags: texlive

I installed texlive 2014 but it broke things I need to finish a book (pgf related things). I still have an texlive 2013 backup and reconstructed the directory. Question: How can I switch to texlive 2013 while keeping the 2014 installation?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about 'reconstructed the directory'? The TeX Live installer does not remove older versions so you should still have a full TL2013. Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: On windows I simply have to adjust the path variable to switch between the tex systems.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right. After installing texlive 2014 on Mac OS I removed the 2013 subdirectory. I reinstalled this now from a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there should be a preference pane in Mac OS that can be used. However, this is broken in my system. However, replacing the symbolic link to texlive-2014 does the trick:

```
cd /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX
sudo rm Contents
sudo ln -s ../TeXLive-2013.texdist/Contents
```

Comment: Did you install MacTeX? That would get you the preference pane....

Comment: Yes, but the preference pane complains and says `TeX Distribution`could not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In MacOs System, the Preferences Panes has a panel "TeX Live Distribtuion" which allows you to switch between distribution.